# Unable to start MySql In Docker Container - Amazon Corretto 11

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to setup MySql inside Docker container which is running using Amazon Corretto 11. I could install the MySql but not able to start the server.

I basically followed the steps given below:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-yum-installing

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall -y mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm
yum install -y mysql-community-server
service mysqld start
```

I am gettin `service: command not found` error when its trying to start the MySql.

I tried another approach to see if i can start the service:

```
systemctl start mysqld.service
```

I am getting error:
 **Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted**

Can someone help me here to find out the right to start MySql?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Can you use the [Docker Hub `mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), instead of trying to build your own?

Comment: I don't want to install the default GA version, rather i wanted to install the version which i wanted. So thats the reason I don't want to use Docker Hub MySql Image.

Comment: Check if os installed service cmd(`which service`), and make sure service cmd in path first.

Comment: **bash-4.2# which service**

_which: no service in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)_

This is what i see